# can N be partitioned into a collection of uncountably many subsets such that each subset is an infinite set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a feeling that this cannot be done.
I need help figuring this out.(Not the solution)

thank you.

Comment: Choose an element in every set of the partition. All these elements form a subset of $\mathbb{N}$, so they form a countable set.

Comment: Hint: If this could be done, then $\Bbb N$ would be uncountable.

Comment: The naturals can't be partitioned into uncountably many subsets, period. In general no set A can be partitioned into a family with greater cardinality than A itself (assuming the axiom of choice, that is. Without choice the answer might be more interesting). With or without choice the answer for the naturals is no since they are well-ordered.

Answer (score 2):

In particular, each of these uncountably many subsets is non-empty and has a minimal element.